# Proper way to limit a button height in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, button

Despite getting more savvy on all the functional capabilities of LWCs, I am still totally lost on the proper way to apply styling.

[image]

This lightning data table is displaying what I need, but for some reason the buttons defaulted to a massive size and stretching the rows. There is apparently an initial width property I can tap into when setting my columns but I tried adding an initial height and it did nothing.

If I want those Fix Hierarchy buttons to be only half as tall, how would I do so?

Here are some of the relevant code snippets:
The HTML that generates the table:

```
<template if:false={emptyTable}>
    <template if:false={error}>                
        <div class="slds-table_col-bordered slds-table_bordered">
            <lightning-datatable
                    if:false={isLoading}
                    key-field="Account ID"
                    data={accounts}
                    hide-checkbox-column
                    columns={Columns}
                    onrowaction={callRowAction}>
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>         
    </template>   
</template>
```

And the javascript that sets those columns:

```
@track Columns = [
    { label: 'Account', fieldName: 'AccountURL', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Name' }, target: '_blank'}, sortable: "true"},    
    { label: 'Global Parent', fieldName: 'GlobalParentURL', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'GlobalParentName' }, target: '_blank'}, sortable: "true"},    
    { label: 'Parent Account', fieldName: 'ParentURL', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'ParentName' }, target: '_blank'}, sortable: "true"},    
    { label: 'Parents Global Parent', fieldName: 'ParentGlobalParentURL', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'ParentGlobalParentName' }, target: '_blank'}, sortable: "true"}, 
    {
        type: "button", label: '', initialWidth: 100, initialHeight: 40, typeAttributes: {
            label: 'Fix Hierarchy',
            name: 'Fix Hierarchy',
            title: 'Fix Hierarchy',
            disabled: false,
            variant:'Brand',
        }
    },
```

Do I need to create my own .css file for something like this? Can I inject it inline? What is the simplest way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's on two lines due to the `initialWidth` value: the label doesn't fit in 100px. Changing `initialWidth` to 150 or more will fix the issue.
If you can't change it, you could add a custom CSS class (e.g. `small-button`) to the div containing the table, then set the line-height via [Styling Hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/).

**HTML**:

```html
<div class="slds-table_col-bordered slds-table_bordered small-button">
    <lightning-datatable
            if:false={isLoading}
            key-field="Account ID"
            data={accounts}
            hide-checkbox-column
            columns={Columns}
            onrowaction={callRowAction}>
    </lightning-datatable>
</div>
```

Please note that `key-field` should be the name of a unique property of your data, so probably it should be `AccountId` instead of `Account ID`. Keep in mind that Javascript is case-sensitive.

**CSS**:

```css
:host .small-button {
    --slds-c-button-line-height: 1rem;
}
```

[Here's](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/buttons/#Styling-Hooks-Overview) the list of available Styling Hooks for buttons.

Just a last thing, you should use [`lwc:if|elseif|else`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-conditional.html) directive instead of legacy `if:true` and `if:false` ones, since they are going to be deprecated.

Comment: Updating the initial width worked- Thank you! and I will look into that if/else documentation.

Comment: @Chris You're welcome, glad I could help. Please consider to mark helpful answers provided to your questions as accepted, to benefit the whole community. [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) you can read why this is a good practice.